# Data Validation Error checking in excel and how to highlight them further to flag the full row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to conditionally format a full row that contains the flagged box.

Within excel 2016 I have setup columns with data validation arguments. Whenever an error is detected the cell is flagged automatically with a colored (typically green) left-hand corner. To go through them you use Formulas>Error Checking and it will go one by one through the errors for correction. 
I have thought about making an additional column with an iferror but the iferror function doesn't detect this type of error. If it did I would highlight full row based on the TRUE/FALSE return of that iferror.

The goal is to highlight a full row containing the validation error so I can isolate that invalid rows for review by a human.

Comment: Why not include a helper column that has an `And(isError(B10),isError(C10),isError(D10))` which would give you a `True` Or `False` based on if ANY of the cells have an error?

Comment: @PGCodeRider Thank you for responding. From my understanding, ISERROR won't mark TRUE for the validation errors. I have tried making the helper column with that formula with no luck in the detection. I tried your formatting to see if I was doing it wrong and made sure to select data currently errored and nothing returned TRUE. To recreate the issue take a column with 1,2,3,4 and apply a data validation rule. Add a number outside of those parameters and you'll see how the error is detected.

Comment: What's driving your validation? A list of cells? Some text? You could probably use `IsError(Match(` to get a result. If you explain the validation, it should be easy to establish a statement to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this with just a helper column that mimics your validation.

If your validation is just a few items that are easy to key in, use the first formula. A `True` value would indicate an error.

`=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,{"dec","jan","febtober","november","june"},0))`

(make sure to note the curly brackets)

If you have a large range, just do the same but alter the `match` to include the range:
`=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B1:B999,0))`